# ASP.NET Core MVC : using pop up window and search for values (id and name)

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

How we can retrieve one row values from the pop modal window table and return them back to main layout as a lookup using ASP.NET Core MVC? ie id and name.

I’m trying to figure out a solution for this issue

Comment: Please add more details . What have you tried and code block ?

Comment: In oracle to have a list of values is very simple in order to ensure that the foriegn key comes correcty from the parent table data. However, in MVC it requires alot of coding to get them. Which I’m trying to have the parent data and in order to create the suitable details for it.

Comment: I think you should share your view page code.

Comment: I do not have code yet still searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popup modal is not usefull it is awesome for developers but not for users.
The solution is as follows:

1. Pass the paramerer/s via url (the foriegn keys) to the destination screen.
2. In the destination screen make the holder of the foriegn keys as a select list and initial them with the transfered keys.
3. Disable the the select list.